# How to configure date format in Highcharts?

Tags: date, highcharts, format

The chart I'm working on is at [here](http://jsfiddle.net/M4hML/).

How to change the date format to `March 02, 2013`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two ways:

- set timestamps for values, so Highcharts will know what date should be used: `[ [ timestamp, 716.4], [timestamp, 994.1], [timestamp, 495.6], [timestamp, 654.4], ... ]` Note: timestamp have to be in milliseconds and a number (not a string etc.).
- set `pointStart` and `pointInterval`, see: http://jsfiddle.net/M4hML/3/

Comment: Thank you. Can it not show weekdays? Ex: Instead of `Saturday, March 02, 2013`, just show `March 02, 2013`.